# MySQL/MariaDB match against letter 'a' and 'i' is always 0

Tags: mysql, mariadb, match-against

My setup:

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.20-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

and

```
show variables like '%ft%';
+------------------------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name                            | Value          |
+------------------------------------------+----------------+
| aria_force_start_after_recovery_failures | 0              |
| ft_boolean_syntax                        | + -><()~*:""&| |
| ft_max_word_len                          | 84             |
| ft_min_word_len                          | 1              |
| ft_query_expansion_limit                 | 20             |
| ft_stopword_file                         | (built-in)     |
| innodb_ft_aux_table                      |                |
| innodb_ft_cache_size                     | 8000000        |
| innodb_ft_enable_diag_print              | OFF            |
| innodb_ft_enable_stopword                | ON             |
| innodb_ft_max_token_size                 | 84             |
| innodb_ft_min_token_size                 | 0              |
| innodb_ft_num_word_optimize              | 2000           |
| innodb_ft_result_cache_limit             | 2000000000     |
| innodb_ft_server_stopword_table          |                |
| innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree                | 2              |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size               | 640000000      |
| innodb_ft_user_stopword_table            |                |
+------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

I'm creating a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
    `s` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    FULLTEXT INDEX `s` (`s`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

insert into t values ('a'), ('b'), ('c');
```

And then run:

```
select s, match(s) against('a'), match(s) against('b'), match(s) against('c') from t;
+---+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| s | match(s) against('a') | match(s) against('b') | match(s) against('c') |
+---+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| a |                     0 |                     0 |                     0 |
| b |                     0 |   0.22764469683170319 |                     0 |
| c |                     0 |                     0 |   0.22764469683170319 |
+---+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

Why, on earth, letter 'a' is having matching score 0?

Same problem is for letter 'i', all other letters are matching as expected.

Comment: Run this command on terminal and share the result into the question `show variables like '%ft%';`

Comment: Thats perhaps the inbuilt innodb stopword list is not allowing `a` to be searched http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html. You need to set `innodb_ft_enable_stopword = OFF` and then restart the mysql and rebuilt the indexes `repair table table_name quick`

Comment: Thank you, that was the case.

Comment: Great let me have it as answer it might help others too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `show variables like '%ft%';` shows from your data

`innodb_ft_enable_stopword                | ON`

Hence the stop word list will come into play

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

For `innodb` we need to disable it as

`innodb_ft_enable_stopword = OFF`

After that need to restart the mysql server and finally re-built the indexes as

`repair table table_name quick`